# Bootstrap equal DIV height to prevent overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3. Below is my layout. How do I make the bottom level of `w` and `x` equal so that `y` would not be overlaped in `xs`?

```
  <div id="rx"> 
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-push-2 col-sm-7 col-md-push-4 col-md-5">
      <!--DIV W-->
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-push-2 col-sm-3 col-md-push-4 col-md-3"> 
      <!--DIV X-->
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-10 col-sm-2 col-md-pull-8 col-md-4">
      <!--DIV Y-->
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" id="nk">
      <!--DIV Z-->
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

**Example**:
In `xs` DIV `y` starts from the bottom level of `x`. Therefore `y` overlaps `w`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap `w` and `x` in a row and add a `min-height` to `w` and `x` like this:

```
.wbox {
    background-color: #333;
    min-height:100px;
}
.xbox{
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-height:100px;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/28/

Also, unless you're still using Bootstrap v2, the **row-fluid** is deprecated in Bootstrap v3+. Just keep a normal row within a container-fluid to achieve what you want.

Comment: And the `min-height` pixel value is just a random value for explanatory purposes only. You will have to find a common min-height that fits your need.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to do with the col-xx-push/pull classes but you catch my drift with the `min-height`.

Also, unless you're still using Bootstrap v2, the row-fuild is deprecated. Just keep a normal row within a `container-fluid` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Glad I could helped Fergoso :)